# .Net Core - Как убрать библиотеку?

Tags: c#, .net-core

После компиляции проекта в .Net Core появляется сам .exe и библиотека - без библиотеки сам .exe не работает, требует саму библиотеку Runtime.
Подскажите как можно использовать без библиотеки ( или можно сделать биндер по типу ILMerge ? )

P.S: netcoreapp3.1

---

По рекомендациям в комментариях попробовал добавить в файл .csproj доп записи

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

в `Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets` студия попросила поставить `false` на

```
 <NETSdkError Condition="'$(PublishSingleFile)' == 'false' and '$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == ''"
                 ResourceName="CannotHaveSingleFileWithoutRuntimeIdentifier" />
```

После компиляции так же появляется .dll файл с .exe

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/2020/single-file/design.md

Comment: для single-file менять Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets не нужно, а нужно было в csproj добавить <RuntimeIdentifier> или билдить с `dotnet build -r <rid`>

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, Подскажите пожалуйста, где прописывать команду? попробовал добавить в события перед сборкой, получаю ошибку: `Ошибка MSB3073 выход из команды "dotnet build -r <rid>" с кодом 255`

Comment: ПКМ по проекту в студии - публикация, выбирайте там нужное и публикуйте, соберет вам единый один файл.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Не знал про это, было интересно узнать какие есть способы или скрипты чтобы было удобно делать. Но возьму на вооружение этот способ

Comment: Не надо путать релизный билд и опубликованный билд, последний делается через меню Build - Publish в студии.

Comment: @aepot, Ну я только начал понимать как с этим работать, в netcore вообще никогда не работал, если я просто жму: "Сборка" - "Собрать решение" - На выходе сам файл и библиотека. Если "Сборка" - Опубликовать Имя проекта" то в один файл

Comment: @aepot А есть разница? На сколько я знаю, `build` собирает лишь проект, а если это .NET Core старой версии, то он даже не поместит в выходную директорию пакеты из того же NuGet. А `publish` любезно восстановит все необходимое, сделает `build` и поместит в выходную директорию все необходимое для развертывания на другой машине. В 3-й версии `build` стал также выдавать и NuGet пакеты на выходе, что позволяет проект развертывать на другой машине (если там нету особой логики) и тем самым `build` и `publish` стали по сути одинаковыми командами, которые для обычного проекта сделают одно и тоже.